# Login to site with js/php code

Tags: javascript, php, json

I've caught this packet sent from my browser to X site when I login:

> POST http:/page_to_login HTTP/1.1
>   Host: host_name
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Content-Length: 63
>   Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
>   Origin: http:/host_name.com
>   X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
>   Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
>   Referer: http://name_host.com
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>   Accept-Language: en,it-IT;q=0.8,it;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4
>   Cookie: __gads=ID=ba4aa3e1f26167ce:T=1420379969:S=ALNI_Max051cucDaIPAjfr_u43Jz3tF-eQ; mlUserID=qoqCnShSTTHg; ebNewBandWidth_.name_host.com=2137%3A1424452854024; ff11_lastvisit=1424960092; ff11_lastactivity=0; __adnt_intro=1; __utma=85431950.643346397.1420379964.1425039982.1425049087.44; __utmb=85431950.10.10.1425049087; __utmc=85431950; __utmz=85431950.1425032713.42.10.utmcsr=dotnethell.it|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/forum/messages.aspx; sly_cook_fc=17313 18 0_; comp_drogat-premier-leagueLeghe2015Quad=0=87834; _ga=GA1.2.643346397.1420379964; _gat=1; rta_nxtml=

And this is how the password and username have sent to the server:

> {"u":"my_username","p":"my_password","aliaslega":"","check":"u1-L12"}

How can I encapsulate this information and create js/php functions to automatically login to X site?

Comment: So: you mean that you do not want to send the username and password inside a POST payload?

Comment: i want of course, but if i sent a "simple" POST request to the site, it don't let me login, so i think that i have to send the information that i wrote too. But i don't have the skill to encapsulate them in a js/php function ;D

Comment: Grammar and spelling